# How to share data between pages Vue in non single page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two pages Index and Products. Both have the same nav where are listed some countries. On Product page when you click on one country which is a checkbox you filter the products and show the products of that country.
I want that on Index page when you click on one checkbox redirects to Products page and filters the data. What I have tried is creating a method redirect like

```
onClickRedirect(name){
   window.location.href = "products.php"
}
```

and I call this method on click of input

```
 <div class="form-check" v-for="country in countries">
     <input type="checkbox" :id="country.name" class="form-check-input" v-bind:value="country.name" v-model="checkedCountries" @click="onClickRedirect(country.name)">
     <label :for="country.name"> {{country.name}}</label>
</div>
```

v-model="checkedCountries" is supposed to save the checked country but when it redirects it refreshes and  it is empty again that is why I used the method and send as parameter country name. How can I save passed name and make it checked so I can show immediately filtered data on product page?

This is the code for filtering :

```
var app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data: {
        products:[],
        countries: [],
        checkedCountries: [],
        message: null,
        page: 1,
        perPage:16,
        load: false,
    },

    mounted(){
        axios
        .get('http://gin.jointdots.com/api/v1/public/categories')
        .then(response =>{
            this.countries = response.data.data
        })
        axios
        .get('http://gin.jointdots.com/api/v1/public/products')
        .then(response =>{
            this.products = response.data.data
        })
    },
    computed:{     
        filteredProducts(){ 
            if(!this.checkedCountries.length){
                return this.products
            }
            const filtered_products= this.products.filter( product => this.checkedCountries.includes(product.categories[0].name))
            if(this.checkedCountries.length && !filtered_products.length){
                this.message = "There are no products to show"
            }else{
                this.message = null
            }
            return filtered_products
        },
        pages(){
            return Math.ceil(this.filteredProducts.length / this.perPage)
        },    
        computedProducts(){
            if(this.pages === 1){
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.load = true 
                }, 500);
                return this.filteredProducts
                                 
            }else{
                const firstIndex = (this.page -1) * this.perPage
                const lastIndex = this.page * this.perPage
                window.scrollTo(0,0)
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.load = true 
                }, 500);
               return this.filteredProducts.slice(firstIndex,lastIndex)
                
            }
        },
        
    },
    methods:{
        changePage (val){
            switch(val){
                case 0 : this.page = 1 ; break;
                case -1: this.page = this.page > 1 ? this.page - 1 : this.page ; break; 
                case 1: this.page = this.page < this.pages ? this.page + 1 : this.page ; break; 
                case this.pages: this.page = this.pages; break;
            }
            
        },
        clickCallback(pageNum){
            this.page = Number(pageNum)
        },
        onClickRedirect(name){
            window.location.href = "products.php"
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: Hi, I think one of the way is to store the country selected in the localStorage and then access the name of the country on the product page. Another way (a better one) is to use Vuex, where you can globally manage the state and easily store and access the values.

Comment: Thank you it worked with localStorage :)

Comment: Vuex is not an option here because there's a full reload between one page and another. LocalStorage works, but remember to clean up afterwards. Stuff will hang around in local storage forever.

Comment: Yes I notice that , I need to clean up when I reload the page but can't figure out

Answer (score 0):

The best, lightest option for passing data between pages like this is to put a query string after the hash, eg products.php#country=france. In products.php, you then need parse the query string. Copy this code into parseArgs.js, and use it in any page that needs to do this.

```
// For static pages, parses arguments after the hash, for example
// myPage.html#myArg=myVal&anotherArg=anotherVal
// In your page, your args are named properties on the 
// args object, so args.myArg
// If you need to pass an url with querystring,
// put it last, in an argument "src".
var args = (function () {
    var returnVal = {};

    var argString = window.location.hash;
    //everything after src belongs as part of the url, not to be parsed
    var argsAndSrc = argString.split(/src=/);
    returnVal["src"] = argsAndSrc[1];
    //everything before src is args for this page.
    var argArray = argsAndSrc[0].split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < argArray.length; i++) {
        var nameVal = argArray[i].split("=");
        //strip the hash
        if (i == 0) {
            var name = nameVal[0];
            nameVal[0] = name.slice(1);
        }
        returnVal[nameVal[0]] = decodeURI(nameVal[1]);
    }
    return returnVal
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use localStorage to R/W. Information between pages.

Here's an example of using localStorage.

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/cfjedimaster/pen/KodaKb)

```
const app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
name: ''
},
mounted() {
  if (localStorage.name) {
    this.name = localStorage.name;
  }
},
watch: {
  name(newName) {
    localStorage.name = newName;
  }
}
});
```

Comment: The localStorage works for that part but when I refresh the page of Products it saves the name in localStorage and it shows the products by that name

Comment: before the component is mounted ... you can clear the localStorage .  this would be in the event of a page refresh

Comment: But also when I window.location.href the page is reloaded